# Validate method to choose atleast one item from the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a textbox which is used like a dropdown (using Css). This text box works like `google suggest`.  When I type in a letter the textbox will be populated with the words matching the typed in letter. 
    on the form submit I need to write a validation  that checks whether the user has selected an item from the list or not. If not show an error message.

HTML :

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="0" style="display: none; width: 251px; top: 143.59375px; left: 28.1875px;">
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-7" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Mau Ramir - mau.ramir@cor.tls.com</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-8" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Mah Gov - mg@gmail.com</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-9" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Mdu ira - mk@gmail.com</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-10" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Mdh Kn - mn@gmail.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is what I tried so far (but not working):

```
$.validator.addMethod("validSmartSrch", function (value, element) {
            var notValid = 0;
            var carts = $("[id^='ui-id-']").children()
            valid = false;

            if (value == $.inArray(value, carts)) {
                valid = true
            }

        return valid;
    }, 'Please select at least on item from the list');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up solving it this way.

```
  $.validator.addMethod("validSmartSrch", function (value, element) {

                var items = [];
                var valid = false;
                // push all the values into an array
                $("[id^='ui-id-']").each(function (i, e) {
                    items.push($(e).text());
                });

                // check if the item exist in the array
                var itemIndex = $.inArray(value, items);

                if (itemIndex != -1) {
                    valid = true;
                }  
                return valid;
            }, 'Please select at least one item from the list');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("validSmartSrch", function (value, element) {
    var carts = $("[id^='ui-id-']").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    return $.inArray(value, carts) != -1;
}, 'Please select at least one item from the list');
```

You don't need to call `.children()`, since the elements matching that selector have no children. You need to convert the list of elements into an array of strings. `.map()` will get the text of each of them and return a jQuery collection of them, `.get()` will convert that to an ordinary array.

`$.inArray` just returns the position of the element in the array, so you need to compare it with `-1`, not `value`.

Comment: Thank you. But it is returing false all the time.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates it?

Comment: for some reason the .map is not returning the text but the children.

Comment: I don't see how that can be, since it's calling `.text()` and returning that.